# Taking Backup of a database in mysql

Tags: mysql, rollback

I have database but somehow it has been deleted. Can i take the back-up of deleted database.

Please Help.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Backup should have been done before deleting

Comment: Big smiley for @MySQLRockstar 's comment. Backups are for before the stuff hits the fan. You haven't said if you're on Windows or Linux? Google "linux recover deleted files". You could also check out https://twindb.com/ - they have a data recovery toolkit. Disclaimer: never used, can't comment - I know that one of their best guys who posts here from time to time is a MySQL guru.